Double folding plane mesh with no distortion in blender
New to blender.
I'm trying to animate folding a rectangle piece of paper horizontally in half and then folding down each side in half on the diagonal to form a triangle.  I've included one photo of the end result.
I've been trying for weeks with armatures but the second folds are difficult. I've tried shape keys but the faces don't keep their shape and the animation is wrong.
Ideally I would like to fold the paper while maintaining its original size/shape with no distortion as I will put an image on the mesh plane.
I've watched various YouTube videos with no complete success, so I'm missing something.
Any help will be appreciated.

Here is a simplified version of what you could do, I've used empties instead of bones (the vertices are hooked to the empties), also it's probably necessary to double the edges to give thickness to the folds, but maybe it will inspire you:

Result once animated:

File: 

... hehe I was trying to find  a solution with empties only on the creases, and getting royally tangled up.

My solution is still not good, it can give a good illusion but for a realistic effect it will need to be precisely worked

Dude, that's exactly the animation I'm after. Nice job. I never heard of empties. Hopefully they retain their area mass with no distortion. I'll look into using empties and try to learn them as well.
Thanks for your help.

@moonboots Still having difficulty with the double fold using armature. I'm interested in using empties. Are you able to provide me with the file you created? Thanks in advance.

I've edited my answer and put a link to the file, also maybe check this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/320021/unfolding-a-paper-map-with-textures-on-either-side/320035#320035
